# Running playwright with the local firefox

Tags: firefox, playwright

How do you run playwright with already installed local firefox?

NOTE!: I need to be able to specify the executable as I'm actually developing firefox so I may have a custom build. But, step one is getting it to run with an official build.

I tried this

```
// test.mjs
import { firefox } from 'playwright-core';

const executablePath =  "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";

async function main() {
  const browser = await firefox.launch({
    executablePath,
    headless: false,
  });
}

main();
```

but I get a bunch of errors

```
❯ node .\test.mjs
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

browserType.launch: Browser.enable): Browser closed.
==================== Browser output: ====================
<launching> C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -no-remote -wait-for-browser -foreground -profile C:\Users\gregg\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright_firefoxdev_profile-SMZBOF -juggler-pipe -silent
<launched> pid=10684
[pid=10684] <process did exit: exitCode=0, signal=null>
[pid=10684] starting temporary directories cleanup
=========================== logs ===========================
<launching> C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -no-remote -wait-for-browser -foreground -profile C:\Users\gregg\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright_firefoxdev_profile-SMZBOF -juggler-pipe -silent
<launched> pid=10684
[pid=10684] <process did exit: exitCode=0, signal=null>
[pid=10684] starting temporary directories cleanup
============================================================
    at main (file:///C:/Users/gregg/src/gpuweb/cts/test.mjs:6:33)
    at file:///C:/Users/gregg/src/gpuweb/cts/test.mjs:13:1 {
  name: 'Error'
}
```

Tried MacOS as well as Window (of course on MacOS the path is different). This process works fine with Chrome

Answer (score 2):

gman, Playwright actually uses a specially patched version of of the stable build of Firefox. This means that **you can't use** any of the installed versions that you might have alongside.

Let me quote the [official documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/browsers#firefox).

> Playwright's Firefox version matches the recent Firefox Stable
> build. Playwright doesn't work with the branded version of Firefox
> since it relies on patches. Instead you can test against the recent
> Firefox Stable build.

Wrapping up, you have to use the Firefox that comes with your Playwright

```js
const { firefox } = require('playwright');
firefox.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www.brokenbrowser.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
  //await browser.close()
});
```

Good luck! If you prefer to use the real Firefox, you can simply try [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) instead of Playwright, which has very similar features for automation.

Comment: Sadly that makes it useless to use for developing sites that are planning to use upcoming browser features :(

Comment: True. You can always fallback into Puppeteer if you need other browsers. But I agree, it would be great if they allow you to use any browser freely.

Comment: Playwright should contribute these patches back to firefox then so that an already installed stable firefox could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your FF doesn't match the version Playwright supports,

The latest [Playwright 1.29.2](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/releases/tag/v1.29.2) supports 107, while the current [FF](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) is 108.

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/19337#issuecomment-1342247868

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20065 raised an issue